# Как правильно обработать запрос из MySQL с помощью PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Привет всем , у меня есть функция которая просто должна проверять корректно ли введен юзер и его пароль , в общем она работает,но немного не так) В БД у меня есть таблица users в которой  две записи

```
 id: 1,  name: pupkin , password:8999;
 id: 2, name: ivanov, password:qwerty.
```

если я ввожу аргументы для функции `checklogpass('pupkin','8999')` -> то выводит  ОК Wrong login or password. Если же `checklogpass('ivanov','qwerty')` то просто wrong login or password. В общем друзья надеюсь вы поможете мне исправить баги в этом коде:

```
function checkLogPass($login,$password) {
try {
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=publications','vad','6989');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch()) {

$users = [$row['name'] => $row['password']];
if(isset($users[$row['name']]) && $password == $users[$row['name']]){
    echo "OK";

} die("Wrong log or pass");

}
}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

Comment: Пользуйтесь поиском лучше, миллион решений и ответов

Answer (score 2):

1. нельзя хранить в БД пароли в открытом виде. Используйте хотя бы md5 с солью, а еще лучше [bcrypt](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php) или [встроенное апи](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.password.php)
2. А если пользователей станет 1000, вы так и планируете каждый раз забирать весь список?

А по существу:

```
$ps = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM users where name = :name and password = :password");
$ps->bindParam(":name", $name);
$ps->bindParam(":password", md5($password));
$ps->execute();
$rs = $ps->fetchAll();

if(count($rs)>0)  {
 echo "OK";
} else {
  die("Not ok");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо) Я знаю что нельзя хранить пароль в открытом виде, просто с помощью функции хотел проверить быстро работу кода.

Comment: Вся проблема в отсутствии `else`

Comment: Ой, да там много проблем, @sercxjo

Comment: Помимо else ОК нужно не echo а return, а die("Wrong log or pass") вызывать надо не из цикла, а после него. 
Наличие переменной $users тоже не ясно, тем более что она не $users а $user ибо каждый раз перезаписывается :)

И все это если предположить что в функции checkLogPass (которая на самом деле никакой не чек лог пасс, а authenticate) уместно устанавливать соединение с БД.

И да, стоит обратить внимание что если соединения с БД не будет то скрипт просто эхнет ошибку и продолжит работу неаутентифицировавшись.

Comment: Ну остальное конечно тоже важно если не для просто поиграться